# How to read Json object with a python wsgi application

Tags: python, json, post, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I need to develop a python (v2.7) wsgi application to receive and parse data in json object posted from another web.

The format of an example JSON object is as below.

```
{
  "BuildId":"4c53575f-36f48a7f1f37",
  "EventId":1,
  "EventName":"Archiving Complete",
  "EventDescription":"Fired each time the build products finish unzipping on an archive server after a successful build.",
  "ConfigurationId":2021,

  [
     {
        "archive_server":"CA",
        "ftp":"ftp://ABC.com/2011_V2/ccoderre_build_dev_build/2011.4.103.002",
        "dfs":"\\\\ABD.com\\ccoderre_build_dev_build\\2011.4.103.002"
     }
  ],
  "Changelists":
  [
     {
        "author":"mike",
        "description":"integrating from mainline\n",
        "number":1233242,
        "status":"OK",
        "submit_time":"\/Date(1305844615000)\/"
     }
  ],
  "InheritedChangelists":[],
  "CustomEventInfo":
  [
     {
        "Key":"ArchiveServer",
        "Value":"buildfsct"
     },
     {
        "Key":"HasSymbols",
        "Value":0
     }
  ]
}
```

How can I use wsgi to get (read) "BuildId", "ConfigurationId", "ftp", etc?
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you got a request handler already?

Comment: There appears to be a line missing after `ConfigurationId`; as it stands this is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the stdlib [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse the data, the result is a python dictionary:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    try:
        request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
    except (ValueError):
        request_body_size = 0

    request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
    data = json.loads(request_body)
    build_id = data['BuildId']
    # etc.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response! I used these code and ran it, got following error: NameError: name 'incomingdatastring' is not defined

Comment: NameError: name 'incomingdatastring' is not defined

Comment: I used following wsgi code, but it doesn't work. def application(environ, start_response):
   try:
      request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
   except (ValueError):
      request_body_size = 0
   request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
   d = parse_qs(request_body)
   
   build_id           = d.get('BuildID', [''])[0] 
   ftp_path           = d.get('ftp', [''])[0]
   configuration_id   = d.get('ConfigurationId', [''])[0]

   ...

Comment: I used following wsgi code, but it doesn't work. 

def application(environ, start_response):

   try:

      request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))

   except (ValueError):

      request_body_size = 0


   request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)

   d = parse_qs(request_body)


   
   build_id           = d.get('BuildID', [''])[0] 
   
   ftp_path           = d.get('ftp', [''])[0]

   configuration_id   = d.get('ConfigurationId', [''])[0]


   ...

Comment: @PeterSmith,  it still doesn't work. Could you please provide a detail solution? thanks,

Comment: @FrankYin: Who's PeterSmith? I've given you as much detail as I can given the information you've provided. Sorry, I have no idea how your other side *sends* the data, for example. Is it using GET or POST? Is it using any compression or other transfer encoding? You'll need to do *some* work yourself here.

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, Do you know How to get "ftp://ABC.com/2011_V2/ccoderre_build_dev_build/2011.4.103.002" from above json data? it is within array. Thanks,

Comment: I also need to get "ftp" value in above json data. Please advise how to do it. Thanks,

Comment: @FrankYin: I stated this before: Your JSON example is incomplete. The key for that list is missing from the data, so I cannot help you *exactly* pinpoint that data. Please do try this yourself, it's not hard. Print the keys of the top-level structure (`print data.keys()`), then access each key to try things out (`print data['SomeKeyValue']`); some of the values are lists, etc.

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, I'm very new to json.  Here is the json data. I also need second “ftp” value. {
      "BuildId":"4c53575f-36f48a7f1f37",
      "ArchiveLocations":
      [
         {
            "archive_server":"CA",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC1.com/v2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD\\dfs\\2011.4.103.002"
         },
         {
            "archive_server":"CT",
            "ftp":"ftp://ABC2.com/v2/2011.4.103.002",
            "dfs":"\\\\ABD.com\\2011.4.103.002"
         }
      ]
 
   }
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, I have solved this issue (got second 'ftp' value). Thanks for your help.